# Designing template using Table tags for gmail and yahoo?

Tags: java, html, css, email, yahoo

In my code I am using table tag align=center, and some attributes with that tag.

My problem when coming to gmail my table template design is at center but in yahoo mail the table is pointing in left side. I am attaching my table tag code in below.

```
<table id="main"  width="570"  align="center"  cellpadding="0"  cellspacing="15" bgcolor="ffffff">
<tr>
    <td>
      This is my main table data.
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
      This is my main table data1.
    </td>
</tr>

 </table>
```

Comment: did you tried margin:0 auto; to table?

Comment: @G.L.P margin doesn't work in emails consistently

Comment: Its better to learn and this site has some good explanatory sections. [**Link**](http://www.emailology.org)

Answer (score 0):

You may try with below options.

- Apply `align="center"` to your TDs as well.
- Or try with `Style=text-align:center` on your table.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9L5uLnm1/) here to check.

I hope one of them will help you.

Comment: Thanks for you help.I solved it by using div tag with align=center attribute